# How do I restart "menu" in Linux mint 15 mate?

Tags: linux, linux-mint

I just installed Linux Mint 15 mate, and the menu crashed so I closed it. Now, the menu doesn't appear in the bottom left of the screen and I can't pull it up by pressing the Windows key. How do I restart the menu? Is there a terminal command for it? I tried restarting, expecting it to automatically load, but it didn't work.

Comment: This is a General Computing question - should be probably be migrated to superuser.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right click on your panel and choose `add applets to panel` select `menu`